# Rearranging element order responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

My markup is

```
<div class="info-container">
     <span class="item1">item1</span>
     <a class="item2" href="#">item2</a>
     <a class="item3"   href="#">item3</a>
</div>
```

I want to rearrange to below when my media width gets to 800 px (@media (min-width: 800px))

```
<div class="info-container">
     <a class="item2" href="#">item2</a>
     <span class="item1">item1</span>
     <a class="item3"   href="#">item3</a>
</div>
```

I have only used angularjs so far for my application (the above code is in a view attached to a controller). What is the best way to achieve this? Should I use angularjs to do this?
Or is the only way to do this using JS or JQuery inside my controller? I dont want to use a flexbox solution.

Comment: one quick possible solution, can you not set the **class** on how to position the **<a>** and **<span>** on your responsive media queries?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article about this problem here:

http://www.jtudsbury.com/thoughts/rearrange-div-order.php

Comment: Unfortunately i think this technique only works for stacked elements I need mine to appear side by side

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to duplicate the span.item1 after a.item2 and have display:none; on it. When the width is above 800px you would display it and hide the first span.

So you would have:

```
<div class="info-container">
    <span class="item1">item1</span>
    <a class="item2" href="#">item2</a>
    <span class="item1" style="display:none;">item1</span>
    <a class="item3"   href="#">item3</a>
</div>

<style>
    @media (min-width:800px){

        .info-container .item1
        {
            display:block;
        }
        .info-container:first-child
        {
             display:none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: eh technically works but it's pretty hacky. if those elements hold alot of stuff in them that's alot of duplicate code just to hide and show

Comment: Yep. You are right. I haven't got a better solution, but I thought I should post this in case it helps in OP's situation.

Comment: I hear you, fair enough

Answer (score 0):

this any good ? ## Edit Doesn't work on SO snippet for some reason, fiddle added
[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5aL1bq0w/)

```js
$( window ).resize(function() {
 if( $('document').width() <="800"){
   var span=$('span.item1');
   span.remove();
   $('a.item2').append(span);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info-container">
     <span class="item1">item1</span>
     <a class="item2" href="#">item2</a>
     <a class="item3"   href="#">item3</a>
</div>
```